# Why iterator is considered functional-style in the Python documentation?

Tags: python, iterator, scheme

I am trying to understand iterator. I notice [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/howto/functional.html#iterators) considers iterator to be a functional-style construct. I don't really understand it.

Isn't it true that iterator has a state inside it. So when you call `it.__next__()`, you mutate the state of the iterator. As far as I know, mutating state of an object is not considered functional, since functional programming emphasize on immutability and compose-ability of object/closure.

Actually, the problem comes up because I want to write a Scheme procedure/function which takes tokens and return a iterator.

```
(define tokens->iterator
  (lambda ls
    (lambda ()
      (if (null? ls)
          '*eoi*
          (let ((tok (car ls)))
            (set! ls (cdr ls))
            tok)))))
```

Notice I have to use `set!` to mutate `ls`, this is how I comes up with this question.

To use it,

```
(define it (tokens->iterator 1 '+ 2))
```

To test it,

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (it)
$2 = 1
scheme@(guile-user)> (it)
$3 = +
scheme@(guile-user)> (it)
$4 = 2
scheme@(guile-user)> (it)
$5 = *eoi*
scheme@(guile-user)> (it)
$6 = *eoi*
```

Just for fun, I also translate this to Python:

```
def tokens_to_iterator(*tup):
    ls = list(tup)
    def iterator():
        if not ls:
            return "*eoi*"
        else:
            tok = ls.pop(0)
            return tok
    return iterator
```

Similarly, the pop() method removes and return the first element by mutating the list.

To use it,

```
it = tokens_to_iterator(1, "+", 2)
```

To test it,

```
>>> it()
1
>>> it()
'+'
>>> it()
2
>>> it()
'*eoi*'
>>> it()
'*eoi*'
```

Can anyone clarify on this? By the way, I am using Python 3 and Guile Scheme in case anyone is interested in trying the examples.

Comment: "Functional" and "mutable-state-free" are not the same thing.

Comment: because this state is hidden inside, and inaccessible from the outside; it is *encapsulated*. It changes automatically on each *next* call, and the validity of the object is preserved. From point of view of the outside observer, it behaves according to some *laws*, is *consistent*, and this can't be arbitrarily changed from the outside. this state is just an implementational detail.

Comment: @zwol There is also "side-effect-free". Is it the same as "mutable-state-free"? Why is "Functional" and "mutable-state-free" not the same? Isn't all "functional" language emphasis on "mutable-state-free"? Am I missing sth here?

Comment: @Will Ness Isn't OOP also has data encapsulation? For example, state is encapsulated inside an object. All you can do is to invoke an object's method. What exactly makes iterator functional?

Comment: the difference is, this object (the iterator) has only one method -- `next`. In general OO setting, you could have additional messages that explicitly allow for an object user to alter the object's internal state. Here it is not the case. -- another point to notice, is that to be truly functional, this iterator must copy its input list`ls` before starting the iteration. Otherwise, with the list itself being used in subsequent calls, the list could be changed by some other means. That's what happens if you create two iterators for same list e.g., as mentioned in comments under chepner's answer.

Comment: so, "functional", as a term, I tend to read it as "without observable state". It is usually defined as "behaving like a function", i.e. producing same results for same input. two iterators (that copy the list), will produce same sequence of results in both cases.

Comment: for a related example, see `http://3e8.org/pub/scheme/doc/lisp-pointers/v1i4/p23-clinger.pdf` and the author's remarks on problems with using generators. With two consumers, the sequence as observed by either one is jumbled up. So, this *is* fragile, depending on the use protocol. The other thing in that paper, streams, in effect add *storage*,  where  the results produced by a generator are stored, so  both consumers observe the same (shared) sequence (because they pull from storage, not from generator itself). That's also what `itertools.tee()` does, IIRC. Or something like that.

Comment: edit to [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064799/why-iterator-is-considered-functional-style-in-the-python-documentation#comment59809752_36064799): allow for an object user to *arbitrarily* alter the object's internal state *possibly making it incoherent, causing observable discrepancies later*.

Comment: @Will Ness Thanks for your link! I think the author actually thinks generator is not functional. ```Generators are quite different from streams because invoking a generator changes the state of the generator. Taking the head or tail of a stream has no such side effect (unless the delayed calculation has side effects), which is why streams are used prominently in functional programming. Generators, which rely entirely on side effects, are simple examples of object-oriented programming in the Smalhalk sense.```

Comment: @AlexVong yes, in general. But in the restricted situation with one generator--one consumer pairs, they are (that much is implied, I think). i.e. that goes to illustrate the frequent point that "C is a functional language too" i.e. *if* it is used in disciplined manner, then, it can be. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an excellent point. Iterators are certainly not "purely functional," the term often used to describe idioms that use no mutation at all. The broader term "functional," though, is more loosely defined to indicate programs that use relatively little mutation, that make use of higher-order and first-class functions, and perhaps most broadly of all, "use weird abstractions that don't look like C."

I think, to be frank, that I would *not* call iterators functional. That is: I agree with you.

Answer (score 5):

The functional *style* is to work with lists of data as a whole, rather than a collection of values you can change at a whim. For instance, if you have a list of numbers, and you want to change the 3rd element, the non-functional approach is to directly change it:

```
>>> lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
>>> lst[3] = "Z"
>>> lst
["a", "b", "c", "Z", "e"]
```

The functional approach is to write a function that take the original sequence and returns a new list with the change made, leaving the original unchanged.

```
>>> lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
>>> new_lst = [x if i != 3 else "Z" for (i, x) in enumerate(lst)]
>>> lst
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
>>> new_lst
["a", "b", "c", "Z", "e"]
```

Neither of your iterators is purely functional, because they do maintain mutable state, although treated as a black box you can use them functionally because the *user* of the iterator cannot affect that state directly.

A purely functional iterator would be a function that takes as input the list *and* the current state, and return a value *and* a new state to be passed to the next call of the function.

```
>>> state = 0
>>> def it(lst, state):
...   if state is None:
...       return None
...   return lst[state], state + 1
...
>>> lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
>>> value, new_state = it(lst, state)
>>> value
'a'
>>> state, new_state
(0, 1)
>>> it(lst, new_state)
('b', 2)
>>> state, new_state
(0, 1)
```

Comment: Fixed. It's difficult to demonstrate purely functional techniques in Python since it doesn't have `let` bindings to temporarily name a function result, which is not quite the same as variable assignment. (The big difference is that you can bind a name *once*; you can't change the binding later.)

Comment: I see, so state is passed in explicitly, making your iterator purely functional, since the same `lst` and same `state`, the iterator will return the same element. Can I further claim Python's iterator is not purely functional because `it.__next__()` will return different element with the same input (which is nothing in this case), an evidence that the iterator is maintaining state internally?

Comment: Correct. That's one reason why, after passing an iterator to `itertools.tee`, you are only supposed to use one of the iterators returned by the function, not the original iterator itself.

Comment: (Note to future readers: someone commented on my original use of a variable to pass state between successive calls to `it`; my first comment and subsequent edit is a response to that. I wish that user had not deleted his comment; it was a valid point.)